# unable to load phantomjs webpage and system modules in karma

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am trying to setup my phantomjs tests to work though karma, but I am unable to load the phantomjs 'webpage' and 'system' modules though requirejs.

here is part of the karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '.',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['requirejs'],

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  '../ext/ext-all.js',
  'test/jasmine/jasmine/jasmine.css',
  'test/jasmine/jasmine/jasmine.js',
  'test/jasmine/jasmine/jasmine-html.js',
  'resources/webclientLogin-all.css',
  'resources/webclient/webclient.css',
  'app/controller/login/main.js',
  'app/view/login/FormContainer.js',
  'app/view/login/MustChangePasswordForm.js',
  'app/view/MainView.js',
  'app/Application.js',
  'development.js',
  'app.js',
  'test/phantomjs/loginSuccess.js',
],
```

this is the phantomjs test code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;

var clientURL = "http://localhost:7001/client/";

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

console.log('');
console.log("loginSuccess test BEGIN");
console.log('');

var steps = [
  function() {
    console.log("Load Page");
    page.open(clientURL);
  },
  function() {
    console.log("Populate Username and Password");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var usernameField = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield#login-username-textfield')[0];
        var passwordField = usernameField.next('textfield#login-password-textfield');        
        usernameField.setValue('testuser');
        passwordField.setValue('testpassword');

    });
  }, 
  function() {
    console.log("Fire Submit Button");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var button = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#login-button')[0];
        button.fireEvent('click', button);
    });
  },

  function() {
    console.log("Verify redirect on successful login");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log(location.href);
        console.log('');
        if (location.href.indexOf("/clientMB/") > -1) { 
            console.log("loginSuccess test SUCCESSFUL");
        }
        else {
            console.log("loginSuccess test FAILURE");
        }
        console.log('');        
    }); 
  }
];
```

this is the error i'm seeing

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) ERROR
  Error: Module name "webpage" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use requi
re([])
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at C:/Users/shining.sun/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/requirejs/require.js?
d84131f3e98422a49aa91d4f87cf96b245726d96:141
```

i'm using karma v0.12.16

Answer (score -3):

"Require" is working only in the NodeJS environment, so it is unreachable from the Karma tests, because Karma launches a browser and directly injects your code into it, so no NodeJS stuff. Same issue is described [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/7)